# Which reference should I use for molar masses of chemical elements?

Tags: resource-recommendations, physical-chemistry, physical-constants

This question is more related to the academical application of Physics than to Physics per se. I'm currently doing my thesis, and it involves a lot of molar masses in the calculations. I would like to know from which reference should I extract the molar masses of the different chemical elements. I'm currently extracting the values from Wikipedia or simply by Google search, but that seems to me a bad procedure. I solved the problem for the case of the physical constants extraction: I now use the [CODATA](https://ws680.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=920686) ones. Is there any succinct paper for the molar masses like the CODATA one is for the physical constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the chemistry equivalent of CODATA is the [Commission on Isotopic Abundances and Weights (CIAAW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_on_Isotopic_Abundances_and_Atomic_Weights).  They have a [website](http://www.ciaaw.org) with the most current data, and they regularly publish [reports on the latest measurements of atomic mass data.](http://www.ciaaw.org/publications.htm)

As of this writing, the most recent published report is

> J. Meija *et al.*, [Atomic weights of the elements 2013](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2016.88.issue-3/pac-2015-0305/pac-2015-0305.xml).  Pure Appl. Chem. **88,** 265-291 (2016).

In addition, the following bulletins have revised a few of these masses since the most recent scholarly article:

> ["Standard Atomic Weight of Ytterbium Revised"](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/ci.2015.37.issue-5-6/ci-2015-0512/ci-2015-0512.xml), Chemistry International, Volume 37, Issue 5-6, Pages 26–26 (October 2015)
>
> ["Standard Atomic Weights of 14 Chemical Elements Revised"](https://doi.org/10.1515/ci-2018-0409), Chemistry International, Volume 40, Issue 4, Pages 23–24 (October 2018).

There is also [a handy table](http://www.ciaaw.org/atomic-weights.htm) on the CIAWW website which compiles all of this data.